# IE9: rotated background images become skewed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, css-transforms

Rotating **multiple** (Pseudo-)Elements in IE9 works fine as long as the background images are referenced through the `content` attribute:

```
.icon:before { content:url('…')};
```

When using `background-image` everything is also OK as long as only one object is rotated:

[image: rotated object with background image in IE9]

When I had to use `background-image` **and** `transform:rotate` on multiple objects I ran into this problem:

[image: two rotated objects with a background image in IE9]

The background images of **both** objects become skewed. Does anybody know the reason and maybe a solution for this? 
This problem occurs only in "real" IE9, emulating IE9 in DevTools of newer versions of IEs is not reliable.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fiddel/662v79Lm/

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with your content url. However, a similar effect can be made using borders on a pseudo. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/662v79Lm/8/) is a quick demo ;)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick help! Your pure-CSS-icon-solution is a nice one for this scenario, but unfortunately the problem mentioned in my question affects many different icons on the website… Seems that translating all the SVG icons to pure CSS icons is too much work to do

Comment: Whilst I can't honestly see what you've done incorrectly, I've used a `rotateX` to 'flip' the icon if that's any use to you: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/662v79Lm/9/)

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you are using an svg. If you rotate it I think it might redraw. IE9 probably isn't redrawing correctly. I would bet that this works fine if it isn't an svg.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question interesting as rotating element is quite interesting

I have updated some of the code .. make the rotation 360 so the things will remain same.

https://jsfiddle.net/aakashshah/662v79Lm/14/

```
{
transform : rotate(-360 deg);
}
```